# Is it possible to run #[tokio::test] marked unit tests via Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

Is it possible to run #[tokio::test] marked unit tests via Visual Studio code? I don't see the "run test" option for such tests cases.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: The current version of the VSCode plugin supports running test marked via `#[tokio::test]` so this workaround should no longer be necessary.

---

I have the exact same issue and solved it by using `#[tokio::main]` and `#[test]` instead of `#[tokio::test]`:

```rust
async fn answer() -> usize {
    42
}

#[tokio::main]
#[test]
async fn test_answer() {
    assert_eq!(answer().await, 42);
}
```

When writing async unit tests this way Visual Studio Code is able to run those tests:

[image: Screenshot of VSCode]

Comment: I couldn't get a #[tokio::test] test fn to compile, but this worked!

Comment: I don't see the "Run test" button below #[tokio::test] on my setup (using the standard Rust plugin with RLS), is that perhaps something only in rust-analyzer or another plugin?

Comment: Switching to the `rust-analyzer` plugin even this workaround is no longer needed. `#[tokio::test]` just works out of the box.